# How to add dynamic value to camel 'To' endpoint url?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to add a dynamically changing value to camel 'to' endpoint url as below.

```
from("direct:getNewData")
   .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            }})
.to("http://dummyhost/12345");
```

How am I pass and set 12345 value to change dynamically in route endpoint url from java service?

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally just use a [simple expression](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) with the [recipient list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) pattern...with this its easy to dynamically construct a URI based on a message header value...

```
from("direct:getNewData")
.recipientList(simple("http://dummyhost/${header.foo}"));
```

Comment: If you use Camel 2.16 onwards then use .toD (dynamic to) if possible